# Nuget packages should be added to each project of my solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, nuget, serilog

In order to use Serilog I had to install multiple Nuget packages to a project. My WPF app has multiple dlls. Should I install all required Nuget packages of serilog to all projects in my solution? Also in general if my solution that has multiple projects, having common Nuget project dependencies, whether Should I install it in all projects or there is any other procedure of implementation.
My app is .Net Framework 4.6 app.

Comment: I would say install it only for the project that's responsible for using it.

Comment: @Rymo If all my projects need those packages? I should Install them to all projects one by one. ie,  lets say I need 5 nuget dependencies in all my 20 projects. Should I install those 5 nugets in all 20 projects?

Comment: In case of the need of using the nuGet package over multiple projects, that's not a problem. You answerd your own question by:

"@Rymo If all my projects need those packages?"

In package manager console you can install it over all needed projects with a oneliner:

"Get-Project *Comma seperated projects* | Install-Package *The name of the package*" 

OR:

"Get-Project -All | Install-Package *The name of the package*"

For all projects in the solution/

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework? Are you going to use Serilog's `ILogger` across all of your projects, or are you going to use Microsoft's `ILogger<T>`?

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete My app is .NET Framework app. Can you help me or direct me how I should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you're targeting .NET Framework 4.6, I'm assuming you intend to use Serilog's `ILogger` to write logs.

In that case, you need to install the package `Serilog` in all projects that will write to the log. This package is where `ILogger` is implemented, which your projects will need.

All other packages (sinks, enrichers, etc.) need only to be installed on the project that actually configures the log (in your case, the WPF project).